# Tightening the bottom bound on eps file created from inkscape

Tags: pdf, eps, crop, inkscape

I have this (image of a) pdf file[image]

I've tried several ways to convert it to eps with a tight bounding box.  I've tried, among many other things

```
inkscape in.pdf -D --export-eps=out.eps
```

and then

```
epstool --bbox --copy in.eps out.eps
```

`inkscape` does a great job of putting a tight bound on the box above, to the left and right of the figure, but fails to remove the whitespace at the bottom, i.e., it produces this

[image]

It's hard to see what's really happening because I can't seem to import the actual eps file, but you can see from the images that the except for the bottom, the pic is well cropped.

Could anybody please suggest how to crop the bottom tightly?

Thanks very much

=======

Comment: just open the file in an editor and change the numbers in the `%%BoundingBox` line? you just need to change the second of the four numbers (y coordinate of the bottom left corner)

Comment: is that  **1** in the first image part of the EPS (if it is that explains the bounding box)

Comment: Agggh, what a dummy, it was indeed the page number at the bottom, as soon as I removed it all was as it should be.    I *really* should have seen that.    Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a page number (**1**) in your initial image which is enlarging the bounding box.